# jest can not parse markdown files in storyshots when i try to test storybooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I got error in console:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

May be somebody have met this error.
Code is simple

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots;
initStoryshots()
```

Comment: Why do you expect jest to be able to parse markdown files? Are you using webpack?